# Cannot initialize a pie chart with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, pie-chart

I am copying the example from Chart.js and I am stuck as to what the error I am making is.

Here is my code (taken from the examples):

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data);
    var data = [{
        value: 300,
        color: "#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    }, {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    }, {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }]
</script>
```

This code gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined

Now if I change the `myNewChart` var to:

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
```

I get no error and no chart.

What am I missing? I feel it's something obvious...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues with your code.

First, you are assigning properties to `data` after it's passed to `Chart()`, so the pie chart will appear empty since you are not passing any data.

Second, the `.getContext('2d')` does not return an array but a singular rendering context (or null). So `ctx[0]` is undefined.

Modify your code as follows and it should work.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = [{
    value: 300,
    color: "#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red"
}, {
    value: 50,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
    label: "Green"
}, {
    value: 100,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Yellow"
}];

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data);
```

`ctx[0]` is undefined.

Use this:

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
```

Comment: ya I have tried that as mentioned there is no chart when I use that